# How to determine if url is being requested from Facebook iFrame?

Tags: python, django, facebook, http, google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine application and I want to serve a different django template if the request comes in from the Facebook Application.  How can I detect that?  I don't see anything unique in the Header.

I'm currently using the URL pattern:

```
r'/user/(.*)'
```

to map to a "user" request handler.  I suppose I could instead do:

```
r'/(.*)/user/(.*)'
```

and parametrize the first part of the path and check for 'facebook'.  This would require that I ensure all internal links served in the facebook iFrame are /facebook/.  Is there any danger in this approach?

Comment: Why not simply use different URLs for the facebook app and the ordinary pages?

Comment: Because I want to re-use the code in the Handlers.  Can I map different URLs to the same Handler?  (then I could simply check the request url for 'facebook').

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple URLs for the same handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.run_wsgi_app(webapp.WSGIApplication([(r'/page/(.*)', Page),
                (r'/user/(.*)', UserProfile),
                (r'/category/(.*)', CategoryProfile),  
                (r'/location/(.*)', LocationProfile),
                (r'/facebook/page/(.*)', Page),
                (r'/facebook/user/(.*)', UserProfile),
                (r'/facebook/category/(.*)', CategoryProfile),  
                (r'/facebook/location/(.*)', LocationProfile), 
                ('/facebook/', BaseHandler),
                ('/', BaseHandler)],
                debug=DEBUG))
```

Then in each Handler I checked for a /facebook/ path:

```
if re.search(r".facebook\.*", path):
```

If True, then I directed to the appropriate "facebook" template.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to detect facebook iframe is to compare HTTP_REFERER

```
import os
if os.environ['HTTP_REFERER'].find('http://apps.facebook.com/<Facebook_URLID>/') is not 0:
   self.redirect('<Facebook_Application_Page>')
```

just beware that it might not be there all the time so detect for the key first.

if your referer matches with your application url then pass the control else redirect the page to your facebook application.

Hope this helps you. :)